# GameHelper Sign In Failed But Not GoogleAPIClient's Sign In

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been struggling to get GooglePlayServices hooked up using the GameHelper object. Upon opening my app, I get the "Unknown issue with Google Play services" popup and a signin error code of 8. I originally thought this was a problem with the way I set up my Google Play Services account, but after recreating it a few times and making sure everything is in check, I started thinking it was something else.

So I tried setting up a separate GoogleApiClient to go along with the GameHelper object (even though it provides its own), and that client signs in just fine although the error message still pops up from the GameHelper object. So I took out the GameHelper object, but then the GoogleApiClient couldn't sign in again.

I'd like to just use one or the other and not both, but it seems that if I use only one of these objects, it won't work. Is there something I'm missing in regards to the GameHelper or GoogleApiClient that I need to set up differently to get either of them to work independently?

Here's the code:

```
public class MyHomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GameHelper gameHelper;
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

private void setupGooglePlayServices() {
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    GameHelper.GameHelperListener gameHelperListener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed() {
            Log.i("Game Helper", "Sign in failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded() {
            Log.i("Game Helper", "Sign in succeeded");
        }
    };

    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    //TODO Remove this for production
    gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);

    gameHelper.setup(gameHelperListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
    client.connect();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
    client.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i("Google API", "Connection Complete");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("Google API", "Connection Failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="my.app.package"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.0.1">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".MyHomeActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
               android:value="@string/google_play_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
               android:value="@string/google_play_id" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />


</manifest>
```

Logs

```
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Debug log enabled.
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Setup: requested clients: 1
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onStart
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Connecting client.
I/Google API﹕ Connection Complete  <-- This is my log telling me the GoogleApiClient connected
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onConnectionFailed
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Connection failure:
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper:    - code: INTERNAL_ERROR(8)
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper:    - resolvable: false
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper:    - details: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR,     resolution=null}
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: WILL resolve because we have below the max# of attempts, 0 < 3
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: resolving problem...
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: result has no resolution. Giving up.
W/GameHelper﹕ disconnect() called when client was already disconnected.
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Notifying LISTENER of sign-in FAILURE (error)
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: onStop
D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Client already disconnected when we got onStop.
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I figured it out and it's one of those "Seriously? That was it?" moments. To authenticate with Google Play Services, you need to have the Drive APK and the Drive SDK enabled on in the Google Play Developer console. If I had taken the filters off of my logcat, I would have seen the following error:

```
07-30 13:00:28.719    2487-2587/? E/Volley﹕ [260] tm.a: Unexpected response code 404 for https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2internal/files/1hV5vzTnhxozzjUvSgct8oUmqdha4xkiF-K_vDD8BEha8aoc6oZLklxxgZmMVHY46C6uzZzk?prettyPrint=false...
07-30 13:00:43.406    2487-3187/? E/DriveAsyncService﹕ Authorization has been revoked by the user. Reconnect the Drive API client to reauthorize.
```

Once I enabled the Google Drive API, it worked like a charm. I'm not sure where the documentation on this is, but that was my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it was the Drive API indeed... 
Go to https://console.developers.google.com to activate it